# Making CRUD request with google Sign In

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, microservices, google-signin

I have Google Sign in implemented with my project built on Spring and JAVA. I can make a GET request to view the json data at the desired localhost:8060 endpoint in the browser no problem. As far as code goes I only have Google implemented into the .YAML of my API-GATEWAY service.

What else do I need to implement to help handle this issues?
Is it a Permission Grant issue through Google Cloud Sign In?

Before adding more to the code here are my issues.

**Issues:

- When making GET request in Postman I receive an Error 400 with no explanation
- When making POST,PUT, or DELETE request I receive "An expected CSRF token cannot be found"
  **

**.YAML code implementing Google Sign In**

```yaml
 security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          google:
            client-id:
```

Postman environment variables(successful token exchange with these settings) :
AUTH_CALLBACK_URL
AUTH_SCOPE
AUTH_CLIENT_ID
AUTH_CLIENT_SECRET
AUTH_URL
AUTH_TOKEN_URL

I have tried granting full Admin privileges to the user account in Google Cloud & OAuth Client ID's section.

Would like to try and work with the endpoints using a google resource but only using the Free Tier of Google cloud and also not sure if that will provide a solution.

Please let me know If I need to provide more information. At this point looking for anything to point me into the right direction.

Gateway

application.yaml

```yaml
    server:
    port: 8060

        eureka:
         client:
          serviceUrl:
           defaultZone: http://eureka-discovery:8761/eureka/
          register-with-eureka: true
          fetch-registry: true
         instance:
          preferIpAddress: true
          hostName: api-gateway

        spring:
         application:
          name: api-gateway
         cloud:
          gateway:
            routes:
              - id: spring-employee-service
               uri: http://spring-employee-service:8080
               predicates:
                - Path=/employees/**
              - id: login-service
               uri: http://login-service:8080
               predicates:
                - Path=/logins/**
    security:
      oauth2:
       client:
        registration:
          google:
            client-id:INSERT ID
            client-secret:INSERT SECRET
```

POM.XML

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.gatewaydiscovery</groupId>
    <artifactId>gatewaydiscovery</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>gatewaydiscovery</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project> 
'''
```

Comment: We need your gateway dependencies, java security configuration and application properties (security and gateway ones as minimum). We also nned the same things for services behind the gateway.

Comment: The first step is to understand what the two error messages are telling you. Neither is related to permissions.

Comment: @ch4mp I edited the post to include the Application.yaml and POM.xml of the API gateway. I don't have a separate service created specifically for security. The most I have done is implement the "Security" configuration. the other service have almost identical POM.xml's I would link the git hub, but it's on an enterprise account.

Comment: @JohnHanley I found that error 400 usually refers to a "Bad Request" of some type. The only thing is that the response google provides doesn't include a subtype with it. The exact alert that pops on screen is "400. That's an error.   The server cannot process the request because it is malformed. It should not be retried. That's all we know".

Comment: @JohnHanley Here is the explanation I found for the CSRF token issue. " CSRF protection usually involves generating a random token that is included in the request and then verified on the server-side. If the token is missing or incorrect, the server assumes that the request might be coming from an unauthorized source and rejects it."    Going based off of this it sounds like I need to implement a way for the CSRF token to get handed off for POST,PUT, & DELETE? Just strange that these errors don't pop up in the browser.

Comment: What a mess! We have almost no info about the "postman request" (path? error message?). You have no dependency on Spring Security in your pom (you should probably have `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` if you want `oauth2Login` on the gateway. Your `spring-employee-service` should probably be configured as an OAuth2 resource server, in which case, you need `TokenRelay=` filter in a gateway configured as OAuth2 client with login. What is your `login-service` made of (Keycloak, `spring-authorization-server`, something else)?

Comment: @Ch4mp So I have all of those dependency's commented out right now, because it was overriding the Google Sign-in screen. Fairly new to this all so wasn't sure if everything would still work through Spring Security login. Before I moved to Google Oauth I did have the keycloak configured to use my employee service as the resource server but then later scrapped it, because I was having issues passing the token(too many deprecated annotations after the most recent spring update).

Comment: In spring apps, Google sign-in is achieved by Spring Security for OAuth2 clients. Note that you won't be able to correctly use the token issued by Google within your resource server (employee-service) and that you should use an authorization of your own (login-service ?) federating Google identities. Maybe should you get some more OAuth2 background? [My tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials#oauth_essentials) could be of help for that.

Comment: @ch4mp thank you! I'm going to give it go using your tutorial!